# copy and paste text + image from NSPasteboard

Tags: macos, copy-paste, nspasteboard

we are working on a C++ Qt applciation that copies selected text and/or images from external applications, modifies it and then paste it back. Since we are on Mac, we are doing this part with Objective-C.

We are having problems trying to get an image from the Pasteboard. It works fine for text, but we are not sure about how to handle images or combination of text+image. 
Since we dont know what the user might select, we should be able to perform a generic retrieval of content of the pasteboard to modify it and putting it back in the pasteboard.

We've try this:

```
//we thought about retrieving some generic item from pasteboard, using NSPasteboardItem
NSArray *classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSPasteboardItem class], nil];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *auxArray = [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
NSData *archived_data = [auxArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Our solution for handling text was:

```
NSString *text = [[NSPasteoard generalPasteboard] stringForType:NSStringPboardType];
string text_str = string([text UTF8String]);
```

It didnt work, so, How can we get the user selection from the pasteboard? 
We need to get the raw bytes or rtf content in order to modify it as we need, and then putting it back in the pasteboard and paste it back replacing the original user selection.

Thanks!

Comment: "we are working on a C++ Qt applciation that copies selected text and/or images from external applications, modifies it and then paste it back. Since we are on Mac, we are doing this part with Objective-C." please the llmd how you copy selected text and/or images from external applications in oboe-ctivec. Thanks. nnagornyi(at)aol.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will help you

```
 - (IBAction)paste:sender
{
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSArray *classArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSImage class]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    BOOL ok = [pasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:classArray options:options];
    if (ok)
    {
       NSArray *objectsToPaste = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classArray options:options];
       NSImage *image = [objectsToPaste objectAtIndex:0];
      [imageView setImage:image];
    }
}
```